# What is the max load Amazon ELB in a VPC can handle?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-elb

I am doing a load testing on Amazon ELB. It is controlling a traffic up to 9TPS. Hear after the response time become increase.

If some has come a cross a this king of situation or if I have missed a step  please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

More than 20k concurrent requests.

http://harish11g.blogspot.com/2012/07/aws-elastic-load-balancing-elb-amazon.html